# What does the line of LDA means in plotting a 2-D plot?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

I am learning LDA and following this online lecturer note [LDA steps by steps](http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l10.pdf)

What is the meaning of the last line and how it can be plot there?
I could not get the meaning.

[image: f]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the *normal* vector of the separating plane. At the same time, it is the direction that you can *project* your original data to better see the separation. The vector the last line is $[-0.91, -0.39]$ but it can be negated as well, i.e. $[0.91, 0.39]$ because right or left (and the amplitude) doesn't matter. It's the direction that matters most when you extend your vector to plus and minus infinity. The slope of the vector is around $0.43$ and the green vector on the image has a similar slope $\approx 2/5$.

Comment: thanks. How to you get the value of `slope of the vector is around 0.43`?

Comment: It's 0.39 / 0.91

Comment: So the above graph is a 2 D, which is output of LDA is 2D. What happened if my original dataset is 20 features, I reduce to 10 features (10-D), so there is 10D plot?

Comment: The hyperplane(s) and the normal vector(s) will be in the original data dimension, i.e. 20D.